# Create Local Policy for one Domain User on one PC

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

Basically I am trying to restrict a specific domain user's actions, such as setting the screensaver, on a windows 7 PC. 
I've searched round the web only to be confronted with lots of help for creating domain level group policy settings but not for the scenario I describe.
I have admin rights on the PC but not at the domain level.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For that specific machine, if you type gpedit.msc in the start menu it will bring up the local group policy editor.  From there you can configure policies for that computer for the user or for the computer.

Just note that all these policies will only be local to that computer and can be overwritten by a domain admin if the push a global group policy.

Here's a good basic link to start with [technet.microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725970.aspx)